# Not getting subtotal in custom sales quote address total abstract model

Tags: sales, quote

I have override `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` with my custom model to add and display custom additional fee to user but i am not getting the subtotal value in it.

I have used `$address->getSubTotal()` and it is returning zero.

Help me to get subtotal.

Thanks

Comment: i want it in collect method.i have override collect method with following singnature.
  public function Collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtotal is calculated right before grand total. This means if your total is caluclated before the subtotal, there is no subtotal to get.

Comment: thanks Fabian Blechschmidt. i have to add <after>subtotal</after> in config to load my model after subtotal.

Comment: i have add added after subtotal but not getting subtotal

Comment: not working for me :(

Comment: This is not helpful. Learn how to debug. Learn to get more infos and ask the right questions: magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 0):

Subtotal can be found using:

`$subtotal = $address -> getTotalAmount('subtotal');`

It worked for me.